# When I'm trying to bring one value from a table with email, the result is always null

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to bring account status from the Registration Table when I'm using the following query this always returns null.

```
public string GetActStatus(string mememail)
    {


        using (Vulpith_Entities objentity = new Vulpith_Entities())
        {


            var some = objentity.Tbl_Vulpith_Registration.Where(a => a.email == mememail).Select(a => a.ActStatus).FirstOrDefault();
            return some;
        }

    }
```

but when I execute the same query in the SQL server It shows the result properly.

```
select ActStatus from Tbl_Vulpith_Registration where email='somename@gmail.com'
```

can you please tell what's the problem with my c# or LINQ query, even I updated tables in the entity

Comment: Please debug through and share with us the **exact** value of `mememail`. _Please don't guess, debug and confirm._ Are you **100% sure** you are pointed at the right SQL Server?

Comment: What is the value of `objentity.Tbl_Vulpith_Registration.Where(a => a.email == mememail).Count();`?

Comment: Give the `ToLower` method a try like this `mememail.ToLower()`

Comment: use like: objentity.Tbl_Vulpith_Registration.Where(x => x.email == mememail).FirstOrDefault().ActStatus;

Comment: How will that help @PrashantPimpale? Why will that **not** return `null` if the current code **does** return `null`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var some = objentity.Tbl_Vulpith_Registration.ToList().FirstOrDefault(a => a.email == mememail)?.ActStatus;
```

update your line as this.

Your mememail should be same as the email as this is case sensitive.

- Answer Updated.

Comment: It would be great to add some explanation.